# Double Y Axis + Bar chart combo

Tags: canvas, charts, chart.js

is it possible to make a chart like on the screenshot below using Chart.js? I tried multiple examples of the combined charts, but couldn't make it work.

[image]

Two Y axis would have different scales. The left could show values from 1 to 200, and the right one even in thousands.

The bar chart would show some values in hundreds or thousands, but not necessarily need to be connected with line charts. All they have in common is the timestamp which is on X-axis.

Would appreciate if you could tell me is it possible to do this, and if yes, some code examples.

I was trying using examples from official documentation, but it didn't work. My expectaction is to get chart like on the screenshot I shared.

Peace ☮

Answer (score 0):

ChartJS supports multi-axis combined charts.

You can assign which Y-axis or X-axis you want to assign your dataset using  *xAxisID*, *yAxisID* or *rAxisID* (for radial charts).

Here's the link to the docs.
https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/

I also created a sample chart similar to the screenshot you shared with the bar chart and red line chart sharing the same y-axis.

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
var data = {
       datasets: [
         {
            type: 'line',
            data: [
              {
                  x: '2022-03-24 23:55:30',
                  y: 50
              },
              {
                  x: '2022-03-24 23:56:28',
                  y: 105
              },
              {
                  x: '2022-03-24 23:57:10',
                  y: 25
              },
              {
                  x: '2022-03-24 23:58:10',
                  y: 80
              },
              {
                  x: '2022-03-24 23:59:10',
                  y: 24
              },
              {
                  x: '2022-03-25 00:00:00',
                  y: 160
              },
              {
                  x: '2022-03-25 00:01:00',
                  y: 11
              },
            ],
            borderColor: '#FC4255',
            backgroundColor: '#FC4255',
            yAxisID: "left-y-axis",
            label: "left-y-axis",
            order: 2
        },
        {
            type: 'line',
            data: [
              {
                  x: '2022-03-24 23:55:30',
                  y: 10
              },
              {
                  x: '2022-03-24 23:56:28',
                  y: 20
              },
              {
                  x: '2022-03-24 23:57:10',
                  y: 30
              },
              {
                  x: '2022-03-24 23:58:10',
                  y: 40
              },
              {
                  x: '2022-03-24 23:59:10',
                  y: 50
              },
              {
                  x: '2022-03-25 00:00:00',
                  y: 60
              },
              {
                  x: '2022-03-25 00:01:00',
                  y: 70
              },
            ],
            borderColor: '#2d78ce',
            backgroundColor: '#2d78ce',
            yAxisID: "right-y-axis",
            label: "right-y-axis",
            order: 2
        },
        {
            type: 'bar',
            data: [
              {
                  x: '2022-03-24 23:55:30',
                  y: 10
              },
              {
                  x: '2022-03-24 23:56:28',
                  y: 20
              },
              {
                  x: '2022-03-24 23:57:10',
                  y: 30
              },
              {
                  x: '2022-03-24 23:58:10',
                  y: 40
              },
              {
                  x: '2022-03-24 23:59:10',
                  y: 50
              },
              {
                  x: '2022-03-25 00:00:00',
                  y: 60
              },
              {
                  x: '2022-03-25 00:01:00',
                  y: 70
              },
            ],
            borderColor: '#8e90ab',
            backgroundColor: '#8e90ab',
            yAxisID: "left-y-axis",
            label: "bar",
            order: 3
        },
  ]
}
var config = {
  type: 'bar',
  data,
  options:{
    scales: {
      x:{
        type: 'time',
        time: {
          round: 'minute',
          stepSize: 100
        }
      },
      'left-y-axis': {
        type: 'linear',
        position: 'left'
      },
      'right-y-axis': {
        type: 'linear',
        position: 'right',
        grid: {
          drawOnChartArea: false,
        }
      }
    },
    responsive: true,
    barPercentage: 0.4,
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
  }
}



var chart = new Chart(ctx,config);
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #2c2f42;
}
```

```html
<!-- Chart.js v3.7.1 -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.7.1/chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/moment@^2"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-adapter-moment@^1"></script>

<body>
  <canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
</body>
```